# UFW insert [number] throws error

Tags: linux, syntax-error, ufw

I use `sudo ufw insert 1 allow 80` but it results in `ERROR: Invalid position '1'`
I am sure the syntax is right so why?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `position '1'` can only be valid if there is already existing at least one rule, so to insert your rule in position 1 you just need to insert a rule without position at all it will be default to `position '1'` from then on you can have `position '2'` or `position '3'` etc ...